# Is there a open source web application for monitor the activity of sql server?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, web-applications, open-source

Is there a open source web application for monitor the activity of sql server? monitor users, queries, performance , ...

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps: [Free SQL Server tools that might make your life a little easier](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx)